Enum in c++ not working as expected, instead is initalized with first value
I have the following code:
#include <iostream>

enum item_type {
    a,
    b
};

class item {
public:
    item_type type;
    item(item_type type) : type{type} {}
};

int main() {
    item a{a};
    item b{b};
    
    std::cout << a.type << " " << b.type;
    
    return 0;
}

I expect it to output 0 1, but I get 0 0 every time I run it.
I've discovered that when I declare items like this:
item a{item_type::a};
item b{item_type::b};

...my code runs like expected.
Can someone explain why? Also, why c++ doesn't show any error in the first case?

item a{a}; is not using the enum value but rather the same variable which is being defined (and is yet uninitialized). MSVC issues: "uninitialized local variable 'a' used" (same for b).

Refer to What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer? and Why is initialization of a new variable by itself valid?

In C++ it is more customary now to use enum class item { a, b }; And then you would use item a{item::a}; for correct initialization

@user12002570 I don't think the dupes are a good fit here. The fact that the code uses the variable itself for initialization is exactly what the OP is missing, since they expect the a used for initialization to be from the enum.

@wohlstad What they expect is irrelevant. What is actually happening is relevant(which is that using self initialization). Just because OP expects something doesn't mean that is the problem. The actual/underlying problem is the same.

@user12002570 I disagree. The issue of the value from the enum is the bases of the question. A good dupe would explain why a is not interpreted as the value from the enum.

@wohlstad No, enum has nothing to do with the problem. Your 90-95% of the answer itself proves that.

@user12002570 but that is what is being asked here. See the title. I agree it is caused by a misunderstanding, but that is exactly what I attempted to answer. Therefore I will reopen.

@wohlstad Again your missing the point. The fundamental problem is the same. The title is based on a misunderstanding. Just because the title asks something(based on a misunderstanding) doesn't mean the question is about enum. It is not, at all.

@user12002570 I think the question is determined by the OP. They asked the question. The fact that they are mistaken does not mean the question is not what they asked.

@user12002570 you are mising cause and effect. I am giving this treatment for posts that I answer because I always answer questions which I think worth a good answer to begin with. It's not that because I answer I treat it differently. And I am not abusing anything - just acting as I believe makes sense and try to help others - which is what this site is supposed to be about.

This question is similar to: What's the behavior of an uninitialized variable used as its own initializer?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user12002570 if you want to be helpful, you can write an answer explaining why the a used as an initializer does not come from the enum (despite the fact that the enum has this value). I know it is like that in practice, but I know less than you about the standard to explain these rules in a precise way.

@wohlstad That is why I provided a dupe with this answer that says "It's syntactically valid, since the variable's point of declaration comes before its initialiser, and the name is available anywhere after that point."

OP issues. 1. Compiler warnings are not enabled. 2. The constructor with a single argument is not declared explicit.

@user12002570 but if you use item ttt{ a };, then a would in fact come from the enum (meaning the enum is relevant). So there are some scope rules making the current a object have priority over the value in the enum. As I said I cannot quote the standard to explain it exactly (I just know that it is so). Maybe you can. But anyway the dupes say nothing about this issue.

@wohlstad Seems like a classic case of variable shadowing/name masking.

@DanMašek I am familiar with the rules regarding e.g. shadowing a global variable by a local one. So does this mean this case is similar ? It seems right because the enum is itself global. I will add that to my answer.

This line:
item a{a};

Does not initialize the new a object with the value from the enum, but rather with itself (but it is uninitialized).
It is similar to something like: int x = x; which is valid syntactically, but uses x's undetermined value to initialize itself.
All common compilers (MSVC, gcc, clang) warn about it.
E.g. gcc issues:
warning: 'a' is used uninitialized

See live demo.
Note:
Unfortunately I cannot quote the standard regarding why exactly a is not taken from the enum, but in this case it doesn't.
It seems like this is similar to the classic case of shadowing a global variable by a local one. The enum is global and the a object is local. If you wrote item ttt{ a }; then the a used for initialization would in fact come from the enum (because it will no longer be shadowed).
Since a is uninitialized accessing it later on for printing in the cout line is actually UB (undefined behvior).
The output of zeroes that you see is accidental, you cannot rely on it.
By using the enum scope like in:
item a{item_type::a};

You use the enum value to initialize a properly.
The same applied to b.
This way the output of 0 1 is guaranteed.
A side note:
In modern C++ is it recommended to use scoped-enums (enum class ...).
They force you to use the enum scope, and so do not polute the surrounding namespace like old-style enums.

I don't have standardese either, but the underlying problem. is that immediately after item a ... the name a is in scope, and later mentions of a, even in the initializer, refer to the newly-declared a.

@PeteBecker I also thought it is something along these lines. Maybe somebody here will give a more precise answer.

This issue is exclusively about shadowing, item a shadows any other name a in enclosing scope, so enum can't possibly be used anywhere after that without qualification.

Thank you very much wohlstad and @user12002570, I really appreciate your help.

@KacperWyczawski happy to help !

tldr;
The program has undefined behavior because the default copy ctor will be used which will memberwise-copy the data members including the member named type using the uninitialized passed argument a.


Can someone explain why?

Because when you wrote item a{a}; the parameterized ctor item::item(item_type) is not a candidate because the passed argument inside the initializer list a is the variable a that is being initialized which is of type item and not item_type.
//---V---------> this shadows the global enumerator a
item a  { a };
//---^----^----> refers tosame a
 

This is because from the variable's point of declaration  the name of the variable(a here) is made available anywhere after that point. This basically means the a inside main shadows the global enumerators named a. Thus for item a{a}; only the copy ctor item::item(const item&) is a candidate because the passed argument a is of type item.
Now item a{a}; uses the default copy constructor item::item(const item& param) of class a with the parameter param bound to the passed argument a(which is itself uninitialized). Note that just binding the passed uninitialized argument a with the copy ctor's parameter param itself is perfectly valid.
The problem is that the default copy ctor will memberwise-copy intialize the data members including the data member type using the uninitialized passed argument a. Basically, we'll have the equivalent of:
class item {
public:
    item_type type;
    item(item_type type) : type{type} {}
    //this is what the default copy ctor will do which will lead to UB 
    item(const item&param): type(param.type)
//--------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---> undefined behavior
    {}
};

You can see this in this demo where the copy ctor is used/printed.

I'm happy to see you decided this question is worth answering. Useful answer, +1.

@wohlstad Thanks.
